# Http Get Request in multiple array

Tags: objective-c

Im getting using http get request to get information from my mysql server by using this code:

```
NSString *urlString =  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://ratemyplays.com/songs.php?listid=%d", selectedRowValue];
NSMutableURLRequest *request2 = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc]init];
[request2 setTimeoutInterval:20.0];
[request2 setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
[request2 setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

NSString *PHPArray = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request2 returningResponse:nil error:nil] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

playArray = [PHPArray componentsSeparatedByString:@"."];
```

This will result in a playArray with 10 objects. Is there a way where i can create a multiple array with first 5 objects in 1 object.?

If not how can i make sure that third object in 1 array and every fourth array in another array and so on?

the data structure can be seen here:
http://ratemyplays.com/songs.php?listid=0

I would like to make it like this in array or something like this:

```
@[@[2], @[0], @[nu6mDd6E1oA&], @[4:02], @[DVBBS & Borgeous], @[Tsunami]],
@[@[1], @[0], @[ b_eyDvsMP8g], @[3:24], @[Henrik B, Niklas Gustavsson, Peter Johansson], @[Echoes]]
```

Comment: A multiple array? Like an array of arrays?

Comment: You haven't shown us how the data you receive from the HTTP request is structured, so that's where I would start: post the data.

Comment: yes array of arrays and structured added.